# Find field value in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to join two tables (say A and B). Now need to search if a field's value of A exist in a particular field of B.

Such as CLASS is a field of A table, whose value is PROD. Now SCHOOL is a field of B table of any record where value is PRAD,PROD,PRUD. Then that record of B alongwith record of A will be returning in Query 1.

Records other than PROD value of A will be returning in Query 2

SERVER:: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: is that a `home Work` ??

Comment: Hi Winged! I was not being able to do the query Gordon suggested. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have a problem with your data structure, because you are storing a list of values in a column.  SQL has this great way of storing lists -- it is called a table, not a string column.  You should have a separate junction/association table with one row per entity and per value, a more normalized data structure.

But, sometimes, we cannot fix the data we are given.  If so, you can use `like`:

```
select
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on ',' + b.school + ',' like '%,' + a.class + ',%';
```

Note the use of the delimiters on both sides.  This prevents `A` from matching `ABC`.

Answer (score 0):

your First Query is........

```
 select * from tbl_A, tbl_B Where tbl_A.CLASS = tbl_B.SCHOOL
```

And Second Query is......

```
select * from tbl_A, tbl_B Where tbl_A.CLASS <> tbl_B.SCHOOL
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query

```
         SELECT
              * FROM (SELECT [name]
                            ,[Amount]
                            ,[unit] FROM [group_by_tbl])  P PIVOT (SUM([Amount]) FOR [unit] IN (A,B)) AS piv
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query

```
                 SELECT
                * FROM (SELECT [name]
                              ,[Amount]
                              ,[unit] FROM [group_by_tbl])  P PIVOT (SUM([Amount]) FOR [unit] IN (A,B)) AS piv
```